# jquery Validation engine won't close prompt

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validation-engine

I've implemented a basic like this

```
 $("#card_code").validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Please correct this', 'error', 'topLeft', true);
```

Then I simulate this error and It showed a prompt, I tried to click it, it won't hide a prompt, I really don't know why, it's frustrating me. I've clicked it many times *until I break my mouse*.

Here is GIF

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0F67.gif